# Dlib face_recognition error from dlib.image_window

Tags: python, dlib

I installed dlib using conda, and am using dlib 19.4. When I run the example python code face_recognition.py I get this output error

python face_recognition.py ../models/shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat ../models/dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat ../examples/faces
Processing file: D:\Docs\Python_code\Dlib\examples\faces\2007_007763.jpg
Number of faces detected: 7
Detection 0: Left: 93 Top: 194 Right: 129 Bottom: 230
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_recognition.py", line 99, in 
    win.add_overlay(shape)
RuntimeError:

Error detected at line 25.
Error detected in file C:\bld\dlib_1504195460225\work\dlib-19.4\dlib..\dlib/image_processing/render_face_detections.h.
Error detected in function class std::vector > __cdecl dlib::render_face_detections(const class std::vector > &,const struct dlib::rgb_pixel).

Failing expression was dets[i].num_parts() == 68.
         std::vector render_face_detections()
         Invalid inputs were given to this function.
         dets[0].num_parts():  5

As you can see it does detect 7 faces, which is correct in the image but when it tries to draw the rectangle it runs into the error. I see the error is from the win.add_overlay function. I am lost on this error or how to fix it, any suggestions? The example code is exactly as is from https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/python_examples/face_recognition.py
The window pops up with the image with one red box around a correctly identified face, but only 1 of the 7

Comment: I have updated the code from the example to use the 68 point face landmarks model. This now works with no errors. Is there a way to use the 5 point model as is originally outlined in the example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an example program from the new version of dlib then you need to use the new version of dlib, not an older version.  **You can't just take an example program for the new version and expect it to run with the old version**.  The new version has new features, which are illustrated in the example program.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I am using the older version of 19.4 as this is what is most up to date on Conda I believe; I will try manually installing the latest version to use with the posted examples. I will remember to compare release notes in the future